# I have a global .gitignore but files aren't being ignored, why?

Tags: home-directory, git

I have a .gitignore_global in my home directory

```
durrantm.../durrantm$ pwd
/home/durrantm
durrantm.../durrantm$ ls .git*
.gitconfig  .gitignore_global
```

The .gitignore_global has:

```
durrantm.../durrantm$ head .gitignore_global
# RubyMine #
.idea/

# Compiled source #
###################
*.dll
*.exe

# Logs and databases #
######################
```

but when I git status for a project I still end up getting the .idea files when I start using rubyMine.

So my git status still shows this:

```
#   modified:   .idea/dataSources.xml
#   modified:   .idea/linker.iml
#   modified:   .idea/misc.xml
#   modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
```

I have run `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global` bvut it didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`gitignore` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) doesn't mention of a global gitignore file.
Only of the global config `core.excludesfile`

But if the latter doesn't work, that might be because those files were previously added to the Git repo, in which case you must rm them.

```
git rm -r --cached .idea
```

See "[`.gitignore` file not ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)"